# Can Flyway check for unexpected (externally made) differences?

Tags: flyway

I'm evaluating Flyway and want to know if it can check for the presence of any externally made changes? I.e. if someone makes a change directly to the database, outside of Flyway, can I catch that?

I tried validate and info but it doesn't seem to notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it can't. Flyway expects you to make all changes to what you want it to manage (structure, reference data, ...) via Flyway.

Answer (score 1):

Here at Redgate we support the concept of a schema snapshot. If you use either SQL Server or Oracle (as these are the database we have best support for) then you can take a snapshot after deployment and later compare this artifact with target database the next time you deploy to make sure that it hasn't "drifted". Our tools can also output a candidate Flyway migration script that will ensure Flyway is consistent with the actual target. If you're interested in this approach I can send you sample scripts of how this is achieved. But remember, this only works with Oracle and SQL Server.

Comment: In 2023, do you have solutions yet for doing this with Postgres and other databases?

Comment: We do. Flyway Enterprise now has full support for Postgres and MySQL is in preview.